# How do we apply the Central Limit Theorem using python?

Tags: python, pandas, matplotlib, graph, data-analysis

I've a huge dataset with 271116 rows of data. I normalized the data using the z-score normalization method. I've no idea of knowing if the data actually follows a normal distribution. So I plotted a simple density graph using matplotlib:

```
hdf = df['Height'].plot(kind = 'kde', stacked = False)
plt.show()
```

I got this for a result:

[image]

Though, the data seems somewhat normal, can I apply the Central Limit Theorem where I take the means of different random samples (say, 10000 times) to get a smooth bell-curve?

Any help in python is appreciated, thanks.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Something like:

```
import numpy as np
sampleMeans = []
for _ in range(100000):
    samples = df['Height'].sample(n=100)
    sampleMean = np.mean(samples)
    sampleMeans.append(sampleMean)

#Now you have a list of sample means to plot - should be normally distributed
```

The mean of the distribution should equal the mean of the original data, and the standard deviation should be a factor of ten less than the original data. If the result isn't smooth enough, then increase `.sample(n=100)` to a higher figure. This will also decrease the standard deviation of the resulting bell curve. The general rule is that the CLT standard deviation is the data standard deviation divided by sqrt(n).

It's important to note that the resulting distribution is different from the original. It is not merely smoothed out using the CLT.

Comment: But, can you expect the resulting distribution to represent the population characteristics to an extent? As in, can I work with the resulting distribution and apply the results to the original one?

Comment: No, the CLT distribution is absolutely different from the raw distribution - the only thing they share is their mean. Try comparing the distributions on the same graph as in your question - you will see what I mean.